# Finding position of pentagon inside circle

Tags: ios

I'm trying to draw small circles over corners of pentagon inside a circle.

I know the following information.

1. The radius of circle is 50.
2. Centre of circle is x = 100, y = 100

How can I get position of pentagon corners in x and y so that I can draw a circle there.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What maths have you looked at to solve this?

Comment: Go through this may be help full http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/polygon.php

Comment: Any point on the circumference of your circle can be trivally derived from its angle a, i.e. the coordinates of a point will be 50*sin(a) and 50*cos(a). So all you need to do is find the 5 values of a for each point on your pentagon. This is easy: since a circle has 360 degrees we know each point is 360/5 = 72 degrees apart, i.e. the values for a are 0,72,144,216, and 288.

Comment: @ReubenScratton thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). I wrote simple algorithm to calculate corners:

```
let center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

let numberOfCorners: Int = 5
let radius = 50.0
var angle:Double = 0.0
let startAngle = M_PI_2

var points: [CGPoint] = []

angle = startAngle
while angle - startAngle < 2*M_PI {

    let x = radius * cos(angle) + Double(center.x) // transform polar coordinates to XY
    let y = radius * sin(angle) + Double(center.y)
    let point = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    points.append(point)

    let angleIncrease = Double(2.0*M_PI)/Double(numberOfCorners)
    angle += angleIncrease
}

print(points)
```

It should works with other polygons. You only have to specify numberOfCorners and `startAngle` (in radians). Correct StartAngle for `iOS` coordinates is I think: `3/2 PI`.

But for default `XY plane` to achieve polygon like on your picture, `pi/4` it's ok.

[image]